# How to change structure of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this structure
[Structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvbPx.png)

And I want to transform it into this one
[Structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwDkS.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample directly to your question body as text, not as a picture. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given df,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'result1':[True, True, False],
                    'result2':[False, True, False],
                    'result3':[False, True, True]}, index=[1,2,3])
```

If, 'id' is in the index, you'll need to reset_index first,

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()

df1.melt('index').query('value')
```

Output:

```
   index variable  value
0      1  result1   True
1      2  result1   True
4      2  result2   True
7      2  result3   True
8      3  result3   True
```